Why is it 'capacité d'observation' (without article) but 'sens de l'observation' (with article)?
J'ai lu dans un article en ligne:

La capacité d'observation a plusieurs avantages utiles au leader. Avoir le sens de l'observation est entre autres utile pour apprendre plus et plus vite [et cetera...]

Est-ce possible de dire pourquoi le mot 'observation' porte l'article après le mot 'sens' mais pas après le mot 'capacité' ?

Can you tell why we say "sense of humour" and not "humour sense"? ;)

La capacité de l'observation signifierait que l'observation dispose elle-même d'une capacité spécifique non précisée, ce qui n'est pas le sens attendu.
Le sens d'observation aurait, suivant le contexte, tendance à signifier le sens vers lequel on observe (la direction du regard) alors qu'ici, on parle d'un sens au même titre que la vue, l'ouïe, l'odorat, etc. pour lesquels on n'emploie pas d'article nom plus: le sens de la vue, du toucher, etc.

Tiens, d'ailleurs, dans le sens de l'observation, observation peut-être compris comme une/des observation(s) plutôt que la capacité d'observation de façon générique.

@Frank En effet, je comprends le sens de ton observation.
